# How to know if a value has been changed in a collection in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I have built an editable gallery which is populated and jandled by a collection - `MyDataCollection`. How can I check if any changes are made into the gallery, as I want to restrict the users from navigating if they haven't saved the changes.

I have already tried comparing two collections by creating a copy of the original one, but that is taking so much time (as my collection size is 15x18). Can you please suggest any better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach you can take is to add a hidden toggle control into your Gallery. Set its Default value to something like:

```
Or(
  ThisItem.Status.Value <> dropDown1.Selected.Value,
  ThisItem.'Numeric Property' <> Value(txtNumericBox.Text),
  Text(ThisItem.'String Property') <> Text(txtStringBox.Text),
  If(ThisItem.'Bool Property' = true, true, false) <> checkbox1.Value
)
```

This toggle will toggle on for each row that has a change (and toggle off when undone). You can then count the rows that have had a change with:

```
CountRows(Filter(yourGallery.AllItems, toggleModified.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Sam Nseir's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006919/how-to-know-if-a-value-has-been-changed-in-a-collection-in-powerapps/78007665#78007665) I found one more interesting workaround.

You can add the following code on `OnVisible` property on the screen

```
UpdateContext({ GalleryIsChanged: false})
```

and set the `OnSelect` property of **Gallery** as

```
UpdateContext({ GalleryIsChanged: true})
```

So whenever any change is done `GalleryIsChanged` is changed to `true`, hence whenever the user was trying to navigate I was checking this variable

```
If(GalleryIsChanged, <My Custom Error Message>)
```

and resetting its value whenever a user is navigating